Microsoft dynamics ax 2012 R3 form opening completely blank
Our project (AX 2012 R3) has recently been experiencing certain users being shown a completely white box when opening the activities form. This issue seems to be limited to only a subset of users.
The effected users also get the form streched which is strange as its set as a fixed size form. Has anyone come across this and found a solution to prevent it from happening? Any tips/tricks are much appreciated.
Can this issue be linked to a windows setting of the users rathern than with dynamics ax?
White box
We have tried to clearing the users cache which helps in the intrim yet the issue seems to come back.
Update 09/12/2024:
We have been able to track the issue down to when users use the windows > close all option. For some reason when using this option and then reopening certain froms they open up completly blank.

Are you sure you're correctly clearing the AUC/KTI cache files completely? Is there anything in common with that subset of users? The cache files are located on the client machine, so they could be on a terminal server or workstation.

Hi @AlexKwitny, yes we have cleared all AUC/KTI files. We havent been able to find anything the subset of users have in common yet.

How do the users connect? Do they all have clients installed locally or via terminal server? Check \SystemAdministration\Inquiries\Users\User log and under the General tab you'll see a build number. Personalize the form and move that to the grid, then look at all the users and make sure their clients are the same and up to date.

Hi @AlexKwitny, users connect via a terminal server. I have checked the build number and they are all the same for the impacted users and it is the build version we currently have in use.

When you right click the white space, do you have a "Show" option in the contextmenu?

Hi @Swedo, unfortunatly nothing comes up when right clicking.

Clearing the SysLastValue records related to the user and form may help.
Maybe the user hid all fields?

Hi @Jan, yes we have tried clearing this and didnt help either. Strange thing is that when this form opens blank when right clicking to open the personalization nothing shows up on right clicks.
